# Android missing option for geo uri

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app using Ionic Framework. Within this app I have some geo uri encoded location links. In the upcoming Android-system option dialog where to choose an appropriate app to handle this intent it provides the following apps: Google Maps and Earth. As I have also OsmAnd installed it should also provide this as an option. Using 'geo:uri' intents from a native Android app does provide this option.

Does anyone has a clue why that happens and how to get this option?

---

Added

Within the ionic app I have this link:

`<a href="geo:50.12564,14.45498">Show</a>`

Angular is configured with:

`$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|geo):/);`

This is what it looks like (my app using geo uri) and what it should look like (wiki entry with geo uri):

[image: What it looks like]
[image: What it should look like]

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example that shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've added an example geo uri...

Comment: This is not a **complete** example as I cannot copy and paste it and run it myself.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I can **not** provide you a full working example! There is a whole bunch of boilerplate code in it to configure ionic and cordova... Install Ionic from here http://ionicframework.com/ insert the above link with a geo uri and test it on your device

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @ericraio Nope. I used a [cordova plugin](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent) that uses native intents. I found no reason why an ordinary link will not work.